# Do the four 'cable'-related tags differ or should we merge them?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've noticed that on the Main-site there are the tags [cable](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cable), [cables](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cables), [cabling](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cabling), and [cable-management](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cable-management). The latter is the only one with a description, which says:

> the term used to describe how one cables up an infrastructure.

I see two options:

Either some or all of the other three tags are redundant and should be merged, or there is a different meaning behind them and they need a proper description.

Which one is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The tag [cable](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cable), [cables](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cables) and [cabling](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cabling) are synonyme, thus all point to the [cable](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cable)'s tag, which is sadly missing a description like you find.

The questions tagged that way are more for the physical aspect of the cable, like length limitation, physical properties, tubing, installation, etc..

For [cable-management](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cable-management) it's more related to the racking and management, as a multitude of products exist to help the cabling management.